# Javascript for loop continue when function inside for loop finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, continue

I have a function call inside a for loop and I need this to execute again on another loop only if the function is done executing, please help me.

```
   $.when(sendData(d)).done(continue);
```

This question is refering to a full script available at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23887807/javascript-for-loop-proceed-only-if-function-called-inside-is-finished

OK, maybe what I said was not clear, I am not trying to have a loop in a loop, what I am trying to do is execute a function in a loop every time it has another cycle BUT only if the function has finished executing.
So I have ONE loop and a function inside it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript allows you to do this:

```
outerloop:
for(...)
    innerloop:
    for(...)
        function call
        continue outerloop:
function call
```

It's not very clear what you're asking here. When a function is called, control is given to that function. It will only hand over control on an error, on a return statement, or when it's finished executing the function.

Comment: so what you are saying is that i should place "loop:" before my for(...)
and change
$.when(sendData(d)).done(continue loop);
to this?

Comment: I'm not certain about the jquery portion, but if you do that, it will return control to the outloop when the function is done executing.

Comment: that gives me an error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token continue

Comment: Here's a sample on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GosuWhite/7TGEC/        Normally, there would be 100 0s but the continue statement returns control to the outerloop.

Comment: OK, maybe what I said was not clear, I am not trying to have a loop in a loop, what I am trying to do is execute a function in a loop every time it has another cycle BUT only if the function has finished executing. So I have ONE loop and a function inside it.

Comment: Got it. Unless it's different in Jquery this is the default behavior. When you call a function, it is given control and does not return control to the for loop until either one of the follow has occured: an error, a return statement, or the function has stopped executing.

Comment: Oh I see the issue now, this is a different issue entirely than what I was understanding. What I just told you is true in its entirely. It has nothing to do with the for loop gaining control before the function finishes, it's about the server processing the information. I can't help you with that one, but I can tell what you're asking is not the issue.

Comment: Right...unfortunately it does not work like that for me. sendData(d) is a function passing data to Web Service using ajax, which is later calling OnSuccess function. It sends data one after another with less than a second break between which does not allow web service to return data back... and thats where the problem is.

Comment: As I said before, I don't know too much about Jquery, but JavaScript does have a setInterval function that executes the function in intervals specified by the programmer. This would allow you to call the function and give the server enough time to respond.

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but it is not a perfect solution as the more data you put into this web service the longer it will take for it to respond